# How to set application path in music21

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, midi, music21

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit.
I don't know what to set on path to application. 
I have installed music21 in anaconda3, but I got output as follows:

> music21.converter.subConverters.SubConverterException: Cannot find a valid application path for format midi. Specify this in your Environment by calling environment.set(None, 'pathToApplication')

What application should I choose? I've seen a lot of pages but no one tells me what to set.

Comment: that should be environment.set('midiPath', 'pathToApplication').

Answer (score 2):

First of all, are you sure you have a midi player?
Timidity is a good option. Check if you have it installed, and if you doesn't, just use `sudo apt-get install timidity`

Once installed, the path you need should be  `'/usr/bin/timidity'`